# DB2: Left Join Over-ridden by Where clause?

Tags: db2

I have a query that uses a left join.  There are some instances where no matching records will be present in the joined table but I still want all the records from table A that match to be returned.  What I have seems to work well until AND TRIM (status) in ('Complete') is processed, which filters out the records from table A that have no matches in myjoined table.  How do I make DB2 ignore the status criteria (table b) when there are no relevant records in it?  I still want everythign from table A that matches the rest of the criteria.

```
SELECT DISTINCT evecas, everef, evetyp, evesfc, eveplc, eveofb,
trim(evetrt) || '-' || (eveprg) as PGM,
evestf,
DATE(DIGITS(evefyr)||'-'||DIGITS(evefmm)||'-'||DIGITS(evefdd)) AS EVENTDATE,
(select stfnam from staffmstr where smmnum = evestf), 
lwsys.isodates(evefyr, evefmm, evefdd) AS DOSYYMD, 
evetim,
eveend,
TIMESTAMPDIFF(4,CHAR(TIMESTAMP(DATE(DIGITS(evefyr)||'-'||DIGITS(evefmm)||'-'||DIGITS(evefdd)), LWSYS.TIME_4(eveend))-TIMESTAMP(DATE(DIGITS(evefyr)||'-'||DIGITS(evefmm)||'-'||DIGITS(evefdd)), LWSYS.TIME_4(evetim)))) AS TOTAL_MINUTE_TIME
,
(select trim (cltfst) || ' ' || (cltlst) as CLIENT from cltmstpf where cltcas = evecas), 
evecnf, evesrv, evecpt, eveamt, evepun,
eveprc, status, lwsys.isodates(evepyr, evepmm, evepdd) AS PROCYYMD,
(case
when evecpt LIKE '%90832%' AND TIMESTAMPDIFF(4,CHAR(TIMESTAMP(DATE(DIGITS(evefyr)||'-'||DIGITS(evefmm)||'-'||DIGITS(evefdd)), LWSYS.TIME_4(eveend))-TIMESTAMP(DATE(DIGITS(evefyr)||'-'||DIGITS(evefmm)||'-'||DIGITS(evefdd)), LWSYS.TIME_4(evetim)))) > 38 then '1'
when evecpt LIKE '%90832%' AND TIMESTAMPDIFF(4,CHAR(TIMESTAMP(DATE(DIGITS(evefyr)||'-'||DIGITS(evefmm)||'-'||DIGITS(evefdd)), LWSYS.TIME_4(eveend))-TIMESTAMP(DATE(DIGITS(evefyr)||'-'||DIGITS(evefmm)||'-'||DIGITS(evefdd)), LWSYS.TIME_4(evetim)))) > 15 AND TIMESTAMPDIFF(4,CHAR(TIMESTAMP(DATE(DIGITS(evefyr)||'-'||DIGITS(evefmm)||'-'||DIGITS(evefdd)), LWSYS.TIME_4(eveend))-TIMESTAMP(DATE(DIGITS(evefyr)||'-'||DIGITS(evefmm)||'-'||DIGITS(evefdd)), LWSYS.TIME_4(evetim)))) < 38 then '.5'
when evecpt LIKE '%90832%' AND TIMESTAMPDIFF(4,CHAR(TIMESTAMP(DATE(DIGITS(evefyr)||'-'||DIGITS(evefmm)||'-'||DIGITS(evefdd)), LWSYS.TIME_4(eveend))-TIMESTAMP(DATE(DIGITS(evefyr)||'-'||DIGITS(evefmm)||'-'||DIGITS(evefdd)), LWSYS.TIME_4(evetim)))) < 16 then '0'
when evecpt LIKE '%90834%' AND TIMESTAMPDIFF(4,CHAR(TIMESTAMP(DATE(DIGITS(evefyr)||'-'||DIGITS(evefmm)||'-'||DIGITS(evefdd)), LWSYS.TIME_4(eveend))-TIMESTAMP(DATE(DIGITS(evefyr)||'-'||DIGITS(evefmm)||'-'||DIGITS(evefdd)), LWSYS.TIME_4(evetim)))) > 38 then '1'
when evecpt LIKE '%90834%' AND TIMESTAMPDIFF(4,CHAR(TIMESTAMP(DATE(DIGITS(evefyr)||'-'||DIGITS(evefmm)||'-'||DIGITS(evefdd)), LWSYS.TIME_4(eveend))-TIMESTAMP(DATE(DIGITS(evefyr)||'-'||DIGITS(evefmm)||'-'||DIGITS(evefdd)), LWSYS.TIME_4(evetim)))) > 15 AND TIMESTAMPDIFF(4,CHAR(TIMESTAMP(DATE(DIGITS(evefyr)||'-'||DIGITS(evefmm)||'-'||DIGITS(evefdd)), LWSYS.TIME_4(eveend))-TIMESTAMP(DATE(DIGITS(evefyr)||'-'||DIGITS(evefmm)||'-'||DIGITS(evefdd)), LWSYS.TIME_4(evetim)))) < 38 then '.5'
when evecpt LIKE '%90834%' AND TIMESTAMPDIFF(4,CHAR(TIMESTAMP(DATE(DIGITS(evefyr)||'-'||DIGITS(evefmm)||'-'||DIGITS(evefdd)), LWSYS.TIME_4(eveend))-TIMESTAMP(DATE(DIGITS(evefyr)||'-'||DIGITS(evefmm)||'-'||DIGITS(evefdd)), LWSYS.TIME_4(evetim)))) < 16 then '0'
when evecpt LIKE '%90837%' OR evesrv LIKE '%T001%' AND TIMESTAMPDIFF(4,CHAR(TIMESTAMP(DATE(DIGITS(evefyr)||'-'||DIGITS(evefmm)||'-'||DIGITS(evefdd)), LWSYS.TIME_4(eveend))-TIMESTAMP(DATE(DIGITS(evefyr)||'-'||DIGITS(evefmm)||'-'||DIGITS(evefdd)), LWSYS.TIME_4(evetim)))) > 38 then '1'
when evecpt LIKE '%90837%' OR evesrv LIKE '%T001%' AND TIMESTAMPDIFF(4,CHAR(TIMESTAMP(DATE(DIGITS(evefyr)||'-'||DIGITS(evefmm)||'-'||DIGITS(evefdd)), LWSYS.TIME_4(eveend))-TIMESTAMP(DATE(DIGITS(evefyr)||'-'||DIGITS(evefmm)||'-'||DIGITS(evefdd)), LWSYS.TIME_4(evetim)))) > 15 AND TIMESTAMPDIFF(4,CHAR(TIMESTAMP(DATE(DIGITS(evefyr)||'-'||DIGITS(evefmm)||'-'||DIGITS(evefdd)), LWSYS.TIME_4(eveend))-TIMESTAMP(DATE(DIGITS(evefyr)||'-'||DIGITS(evefmm)||'-'||DIGITS(evefdd)), LWSYS.TIME_4(evetim)))) < 38 then '.5'
when evecpt LIKE '%90837%' OR evesrv LIKE '%T001%' AND TIMESTAMPDIFF(4,CHAR(TIMESTAMP(DATE(DIGITS(evefyr)||'-'||DIGITS(evefmm)||'-'||DIGITS(evefdd)), LWSYS.TIME_4(eveend))-TIMESTAMP(DATE(DIGITS(evefyr)||'-'||DIGITS(evefmm)||'-'||DIGITS(evefdd)), LWSYS.TIME_4(evetim)))) < 16 then '0'
when evecpt LIKE '%90792%' then '1'
when evecpt LIKE '%90831%' then '.25'
when evecpt LIKE '%90833%' then '.25'
when evecpt LIKE '%90836%' then '1'
when evecpt LIKE '%90838%' then '1'
when evecpt LIKE '%T004%' then '1'
when evecpt LIKE '%T003%' then '1'
when evecpt LIKE '%T002%' then '1'
when evecpt LIKE '%90853%' then '.25'
when evecpt LIKE '%90870%' then '.55'
when evecpt LIKE '%96372%' then '.2'
when evecpt LIKE '%99212%' then '.25'
when evecpt LIKE '%99213%' then '.33'
when evecpt LIKE '%99214%' then '.5'
when evecpt LIKE '%99215%' then '1'
when evecpt LIKE '%E001%' then 'NONE'
when evecpt LIKE '%G001%' then 'NONE'
when evecpt LIKE '%I001%' then 'NONE'
when evecpt LIKE '%L001%' then 'NONE'
when evecpt LIKE '%M001%' then 'NONE'
when evecpt LIKE '%P010%' then 'NONE'
when evecpt LIKE '%TP05%' then '.5'
when evecpt LIKE '%TP10%' then '1'
when evecpt LIKE '%TP15%' then '1.5'
when evecpt LIKE '%TP20%' then '2'
when evecpt LIKE '%TP25%' then '2.5'
when evecpt LIKE '%TP30%' then '3'
when evecpt LIKE '%TP35%' then '3.5'
when evecpt LIKE '%TP40%' then '4'
when evecpt LIKE '%TP45%' then '4.5'
when evecpt LIKE '%TP50%' then '5'
when evecpt LIKE '%TP55%' then '5.5'
when evecpt LIKE '%TP60%' then '6'
when evecpt LIKE '%T099%' then 'NONE'
when evecpt LIKE '%T100%' then 'NONE'
when evecpt LIKE '%TP01%' then 'NONE'
when evecpt LIKE '%H0032%' then 'NONE'
when evecpt LIKE '%H0035%' then 'NONE'
when evecpt LIKE '%P010%' then 'NONE'
when evecpt LIKE '%99221%' then '.5'
when evecpt LIKE '%99222%' then '1.5'
when evecpt LIKE '%99223%' then '1.5'
when evecpt LIKE '%99231%' then '.5'
when evecpt LIKE '%99232%' then '.5'
when evecpt LIKE '%99233%' then '.5'
when evecpt LIKE '%99238%' then '.5'
when evecpt LIKE '%99239%' then '.5'
when evecpt LIKE '%99408%' then '.5'
when evecpt LIKE '%99409%' then '1'
when evecpt LIKE '%G0177%' then '.25'
when evecpt LIKE '%G0410%' then '.25'
when evecpt LIKE '%G0176%' then '.25'
when evecpt LIKE '%T007%' then '.25'
when evecpt LIKE '%T005%' then '.25'
when evecpt LIKE '%T006%' then '.25'
when evecpt LIKE '%T002%' then '1'
when evecpt LIKE '%T003%' then '1'
ELSE NULL
END
) AS VALUE
--  from evetrnpf, doctsk
from evetrnpf
LEFT JOIN doctsk AS DT ON DT.evetrn_id = everef AND DT.client_id = evecas 
WHERE lwsys.isodates(evefyr, evefmm, evefdd) BETWEEN ? AND ?
AND TRIM (status) in ('Complete')
AND evetyp = 'S'
 AND evecas <> 0
ORDER BY stfnam, evecas
```

Answer (score 5):

> DB2: Left Join Over-ridden by Where clause?

If you add search arguments to the where clause, it is going to filter that out, even if it is a left join. As the where clause is processed after the left join. If you want to keep the records even if

```
Status != ('Complete')
```

Try changing this

```
LEFT JOIN doctsk AS DT ON DT.evetrn_id = everef AND DT.client_id = evecas 
WHERE lwsys.isodates(evefyr, evefmm, evefdd) BETWEEN ? AND ?
AND TRIM (status) in ('Complete')
```

To this:

```
LEFT JOIN doctsk AS DT ON DT.evetrn_id = everef AND DT.client_id = evecas    
AND TRIM (status) in ('Complete')
WHERE lwsys.isodates(evefyr, evefmm, evefdd) BETWEEN ? AND ?
```

**EDIT 2**

On `AND TRIM (status) <> ''` returns everything with my dataset:

Query

```
   SELECT DISTINCT * 
   FROM evetrnpf
   LEFT JOIN doctsk AS DT ON DT.evetrn_id = everef AND DT.client_id = evecas 
   AND TRIM (status) <> '';
```

[image]

**EDIT**

> In fact, I get the same number of results even after I comment the
>   "AND TRIM (status) in ('Complete')" out as with it in

That is normal behaviour since you are doing a `LEFT JOIN`
as requested with this question:

> How do I make DB2 ignore the status criteria (table b) when there are
>   no relevant records in it?

**Example of this behaviour:**

**Query:**

```
SELECT DISTINCT * 
FROM evetrnpf
LEFT JOIN doctsk AS DT ON DT.evetrn_id = everef AND DT.client_id = evecas 
AND TRIM (status) in ('Complete');
```

**RESULT:**

[image]

**Test Data**
    CREATE TABLE doctsk (   evetrn_id  int,status varchar(20), client_id varchar(20) );

```
INSERT INTO doctsk(evetrn_id,status,client_id)

VALUES(1,'  Complete  ',1);


INSERT INTO doctsk(evetrn_id,status,client_id)

VALUES(2,'  NOTComplete  ',2);


INSERT INTO doctsk(evetrn_id,status,client_id)

VALUES(3,'Complete  ',3);


INSERT INTO doctsk(evetrn_id,status,client_id)

VALUES(4,'   Complete',4);


CREATE TABLE evetrnpf  (    everef   int,val varchar(20),evecas  int);

INSERT INTO evetrnpf(everef,val,evecas)

VALUES(1,'bla',1);



INSERT INTO evetrnpf(everef,val,evecas)

VALUES(2,'bla',2);

INSERT INTO evetrnpf(everef,val,evecas)

VALUES(3,'bla',3);

INSERT INTO evetrnpf(everef,val,evecas)

VALUES(4,'bla',4);
```

Comment: The only records I am getting with the suggested change are of NULL status.  Where are the ones that match "Complete"?

Comment: In fact, I get the same number of results even after I comment the "AND TRIM (status) in ('Complete')" out as with it in.

Comment: @user173705 which is normal, since you are doing a LEFT JOIN and adding the status criteria to it. I added an example. My understanding was that you need to get all the values from evetrnpf even if they don't match the Status criteria in doctsk?

Comment: Well, it is "Normal" but why did you suggest that when it won't work in this case?  "My understanding was that you need to get all the values from evetrnpf even if they don't match the Status criteria in doctsk?" - Yes.  I need to retain my "LEFT JOIN" and only include the status criteria WHEN matching records are present.

Comment: I suggested it since the values from B that have status = complete will have a value in that column. Other non matches will have NULL. As a result these NULL values are not filtered from the result set.  As to answer the "get all the values from evetrnpf even if they don't match the Status criteria in doctsk?" question. As my example shows.

Comment: I understand what you are saying but when the code provided is implemented only NULL values on B are being returned.

Comment: Would it be possible to add a conditional WHERE/AND clause?  Similar to:  CASE WHEN evecpt in ('value1', 'value2') THEN AND TRIM (status) in ('Complete') END

Comment: I think you could, I am not 100% following on what you would need. To me now, it looks like you would add an extra filter to the left join,  (evecpt in ('value1', 'value2') AND TRIM (status) in ('Complete') ) which will return even less to the select. Or do you just need Complete to be returned by the select statement when evecpt is in value1 or value2?

Comment: When I do this (as suggested): LEFT JOIN doctsk AS DT ON DT.evetrn_id = everef AND DT.client_id = evecas
AND TRIM (status) <> '' : Only NULL values are returned, so it is being ignored.  Why bother even having it?

Comment: @user173705 then either the other values are not matching or status is indeed '' OR you are Concatenating columns where one or more columns have NULL values in the select clause. e.g. one column has 5 as a value + other column that has  NULL  as the value, returns NULL or something else is going on. Check my Edit 2 for the result on my dataset.